# Cannot get _pull to work using LoDash

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm trying to remove an object from an array using LoDash.

```
var roomList = [
    {id: '12345', room: 'kitchen'},
    {id: '23456', room: 'lounge'},
    {id: '34567', room: 'bathroom'},
];

console.log(roomList); //outputs all 3 rooms
_.pull(roomList, {id: '12345'});
console.log(roomList); //STILL outputs all 3 rooms!
```

I thought `_pull` would work in this scenario but it doesn't. How can I remove an object from an array using LoDash?

Comment: it works for arrays, but not for an array of objects. if you check the code, it compares array values with the ones you give and `{id: '12345'} === {id: '12345', room: 'kitchen'}` will return false

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can remove an object from an array then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var roomList = [
    {id: '12345', room: 'kitchen'},
    {id: '23456', room: 'lounge'},
    {id: '34567', room: 'bathroom'},
];

console.log(roomList);
_.pull(roomList, _.find(roomList, {id: '12345'}));
console.log(roomList);
```

Comment: This seems to work but I'm not sure why? Looking at the docs `_find` returns an object too so it's effectively the same as my code. Thanks by the way.

Comment: `_.find` returns element and `_.pull` method use strict equality for comparisons (===).
John-David Dalton says that you can use `_.remove` method and it is probably better solution than my solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [_.remove](http://lodash.com/docs#remove):

```
_.remove(roomList, {id: '12345'});
```

Comment: Thanks for this John - works well - thought I had to use a callback with `remove`

Comment: `_.remove` and several other methods support "\_.pluck" & "\_.where" style callback shorthands. By supplying the object the method create a callback that will perform a partial compare of the object against elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `_.filter`;

```
roomList = _.filter(roomList, function(item) {return item.id != '12345'});
console.log(roomList);
```